# Fast Linear actuator

Tags: electrical, electronics, diy, motors

Hi Im looking for some sort of linear actuator for diy chicken coop project with a 200mm travel, 
and atleast 100mm/s speed, but generally the faster the better, force between 10 and 35lbs(5 to 15kg)

I have looked online and linear actuator all seem to be VERY slow typically 10mm/s
but have an excess of force. typically 150kg. belt driven systems seem to be faster but are much more expensive.  I would ideally like to avoid a 1:20 lever arm but im not sure what else i can use to get the speed and travel. rc servos seem to not be quite enough 30k/cm is considered high torque. with a servo arm of 20cm and a 60 degree arm it would leave just 1.5kg force at the end. and i'm not sure that would be enough force but would be very fast. w what other options do i have for cheapish(£30-£50) linear motion.

Comment: You might have more luck with this question in Robotics. Voting to close because it is not related to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair.

Comment: Sites that may be of use to you: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/ and http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (if Robotics doesn't like the price-shopping thing).

Comment: https://www.firgelliauto.com/products/mini-track-actuator

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered modifying your design to utilise springs or perhaps use a spring in tandem with an actuator?